# Can I cancel a HTTP response after headers are sent?

Tags: node.js, http

On a node HTTP server I'm spawning a process and streaming the output to the response.

When the process returns I'd like to indicate to the client if an error occured. Obviously I can't set the HTTP status code as the headers were already sent.

Is there a way to abort the connection?

E.g.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('Hello World\n');

  // how do I abort the request at this point 
  // and indicate an error to the client?
  // e.g. curl should return != 0

  res.end();
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: what happens when you throw an error before calling `res.end()`?

Comment: you mean `res.emit("error", ...)`? the client still gets a success response.

Comment: No, really just throw an error so `res.end()` is never reached. This may abort the response, indicating a failure to the client.

Comment: Interesting idea but I don't want my node process to exit. Not calling res.end() will keep the connection open until the client gets a timeout. I'd rather abort the connection immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/2gIsWPj43lI), you can use

- either `req.client.destroy();`
- or `res.connection.destroy();`

curl will then report

> curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

Answer (score 0):

```
var thirdPartyApp = $express();

thirdPartyApp.use('/error/', function (req, res) {

    console.log('error');

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('aye');

    throw 'booboo!';

    res.end();
});
```

On `expressjs` this does not kill the node process (probably just need to bind to the error event) but does immediately kill the response, indicating an error to the user without a timeout.

Comment: express is nearly the same as `http`, notice how the function signature is identical to your example (the `req, res` arguments).