# Kill response stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If I encounter an error after headers have been sent I need to be able to "kill" the connection in order to signal to the client that something went wrong. How do I do this i NodeJS/ExpressJS?

```
function (req, res, next) {
  createStream()
    .on('error', () => {
       if (res.headersSent) {
          /* KILL CONNECTION */
       } else {
          res.sendStatus(500)
       }
    })
    .pipe(res)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Error: Can't set headers after they are sent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Comment: @NirLevy: I know you can't set headers after they are sent. That the whole point of the question. I want to kill the connection... how is it a duplicate?

Comment: Maybe duplicate here: [Can I cancel a HTTP response after headers are sent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31854487/can-i-cancel-a-http-response-after-headers-are-sent)

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: Yep, thanks!